# Error too many values to unpack

Tags: html, python, django, django-models, django-forms

Cuando lleno el formulario, los datos me los guarda correctamente en la base de datos, pero no me vuelve a funcionar el formulario y me aparece el error "too many values to unpack". ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Acá esta mi template:

```
<div class="col-md-20 animate-box">
            <h3></h3>
            <form method="post">{% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary">

                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
```

Mi vista:

```
def post(self, request):

        form =self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'La venta se adiciono correctamente ')

        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'La venta no se pudo adicionar')

        return render(request, 'listar_contratos.html')
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. Debes [edit] y mejorar tu pregunta. Agrega en la pregunta qué has intentado, qué errores tienes, etc.

Comment: podrias agregar mas detalle de tu error el famoso trace que genera django

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no le estás pasando el contexto. Recuerda que para mostrar el formulario en el template tienes que pasarle el formulario en el contexto. El contexto no es más que un diccionario con los datos:

```
def post(self, request):

    form =self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'La venta se adiciono correctamente ')

    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'La venta no se pudo adicionar')

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'listar_contratos.html', context)
```

Por lo que veo, estás usando `form_class` así que asumo que tu vista está heredando de `FormView` directa o indirectamente. Si lo único que quieres hacer es mostrar mensajes, existen unos métodos especiales para cuando el formulario es válido o inválido:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    # Cuando los datos en el formulario son válidos.
    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'La venta se adiciono correctamente ')
    return super().form_valid(form)


def form_invalid(self, form):
    # Cuando los datos en el formulario son inválidos.
    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR, 'La venta no se pudo adicionar')
    return super().form_invalid(form)
```

Observa que en los mensajes estoy usando `self.request`.